# Special characters break alignment in formatting

Tags: python, string, formatting, alignment

Aloha, i've some strings which i'm nicely formatting with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) this way:

```
strings = [
   'Aloha',
   'SomeString',
   'Special ´ char',
   'Numb3rsAndStuff'
]

for string in strings:
    print('> {:<20} | more text <'.format(string))
```

This gives me this output:

```
Aloha                | more text <
strings              | more text <
Special ´ char      | more text <
Numb3rs              | more text <
```

As you can see, the special character breaks the alignment. What can i do about this? I don't want this disrcrepancy ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 exhibits this problem if you are using ordinary strings, because the special character you included is represented by the two characters `'\xc2\xb4'`, taking up two spaces. It will work ok if you use unicode strings. That involves putting a `u` in front of your string literals.

```
strings = [
   u'Aloha',
   u'SomeString',
   u'Special ´ char',
   u'Numb3rsAndStuff'
]

for string in strings:
    print(u'> {:<20} | more text <'.format(string))
```

Output:

```
Aloha                | more text <
SomeString           | more text <
Special ´ char       | more text <
Numb3rsAndStuff      | more text <
```

In Python 3 this wouldn't happen because all the strings are unicode strings.

Comment: The reason being that `\`` is represented by the two-character string `'\xc2\xb4'` in UTF-8.  When aligning the strings as byte strings, Python simply counts bytes, not UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks. Edited to include that.

Comment: Thanks, but if i call `unicode('nice´ stuff')`, i get an `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2`

Comment: @Tim: Try `'nice\` stuff'.decode('utf8')`, assuming the string is encoded in UTF-8.